# What is the overall life expectancy across in the world? (with numpy )

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

https://hub.jovian.ml/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/countries.csv

I am using the above data for practicing pandas and NumPy methods.

I want to find overall life expectancy for that I am using the average function of NumPy

```
np.average(countries_df["life_expectancy"], weights=countries_df["population"])
```

but this is giving me `nan`.

how can I get the right answer using NumPy?

using the below method I am getting the right answer.

```
(countries_df['life_expectancy']*countries_df['population']).sum() / countries_df['population'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove empty values before doing average:

```
aux_df = countries_df.dropna(subset=['life_expectancy','population'])
np.average(aux_df["life_expectancy"], weights=aux_df["population"])
>> 72.7416
```

The second method you mentioned is not correct, you need to filter nan values in "life_expectancy" before doing the sum of population at division:

```
(countries_df['life_expectancy']*countries_df['population']).sum() / countries_df[~countries_df['life_expectancy'].isna()]['population'].sum()
>> 72.7416
```

**EDIT**

Sample data:

```
+-----------------+------------+-----------------------------+
| Life Expectancy | Population | Life Expetancy * Population |
+-----------------+------------+-----------------------------+
| 70              |        500 | 35000                       |
| 71              |       1000 | 71000                       |
| nan             |       2000 | nan                         |
+-----------------+------------+-----------------------------+
Sum:                      3500   106000
```

Using your second method: 106000/3500 = 30.28 (clearly incorrect)

If we delete nan rows before we perform the calculation we get the following table

```
+-----------------+------------+-----------------------------+
| Life Expectancy | Population | Life Expetancy * Population |
+-----------------+------------+-----------------------------+
|              70 |        500 | 35000                       |
|              71 |       1000 | 71000                       |
+-----------------+------------+-----------------------------+
Sum:                      1500   106000
```

Result: 106000/1500 = 70.66

If you multiply a number by nan you will get a nan. When you sum all the values pandas just ignore nan values and sum the rest unlike numpy.sum which if there is a nan it will return nan too

Comment: how ```nan``` values are affecting the result in the second method I've mentioned